# Is there a shortage of accounting professors?

Tags: phd, research-process, professorship, economics, supporting-information

I spoke with an economics professor recently (before he passed away) and he made a claim to me that I thought was interesting: that there is a shortage of accounting professors, and so a PhD in Accounting would be valuable for both academia and industry.

Is there any data available that backs up this claim?

Comment: I get lots of recruiting emails for accounting professors.  I've never studied accounting.

Comment: Such shortages typically depend on the country, so mentioning that would be useful. Moreover, beware of the [pork cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_cycle): by the time you are eligible to become professor the shortage may well have turned into a surplus.

Comment: Students who study accounts go on to the industry ,very rarely to academia

Comment: @MaartenBuis - excellent point about the "pork cycle".